# dynamic string in bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I would like to create a dynamic boostrap table query but it's not working.

My table is:

```
<table  
                  th:id="'view'+${label}"
                  data-minimum-count-columns="2"
                  data-show-pagination-switch="true"
                  data-pagination="true"
                  data-id-field="id"
                  data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
                  data-side-pagination="client"
                  data-click-to-select="true"
                  data-show-refresh="true"
                  data-url="${view}"
                  >
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                      <th data-field="id" >Netex Id</th>
                      <th data-field="name.value">Item Name</th>
                      <th data-field="version">Version</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
              </table>
```

My jquery event can be:

```
$('#view'+[[${label}]]).bootstrapTable({
    data: discountingRuleData,
    pagination: true
});
```

I got error because the `'#view'+[[${label}]]` is not working.
The error is:

> > jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot create property 'state' on string 'i'
> >
> > TypeError: Cannot create property 'state' on string 'i'

Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try var tableSelector = '#view'+[[${label}]]; and then console log the tableselector and see if its the same id as the table?

Comment: I tried: var tableSelector = '#view'+[[${label}]]; and after the console.log(tableSelector) The result is #viewDiscountingRule This is fine but I got the same error if I use the tableSelector variable in the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The # is a special character so I need to use \ in the string.
So the result is 
$("\\#view"+[[${label}]]).bootstrapTable({
    data: discountingRuleData,
    pagination: true
});